# phpmyadmin how to remove certain text from a field?

Tags: phpmyadmin, remove-if

I have a table called products which has a field called products_description, how can I remove certain text from the fields for example if the text abc exists then remove it from all products?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run a query

```
select * from products where products_description like '%abc%'
```

and for each result do

```
new_description = str_replace('abc','',old_description);
```

and run an update query with the new description.